# Google analytics event tracking doesn't show the related revenue

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, ecommerce, tracking, click-tracking

We're tracking clicks on certain banners on a site using synchroneous tracking:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(\''+ ga_acc_code +'\');
pageTracker._trackEvent(\'click_1\', \'Home\', \'%title%\');
```

The site uses asynchroneous tracking and this is synchroneous tracking. But it works and the events *are* being registered.

The site analytics is in "ecommerce mode".

On the Top Events report we don't see revenues for these segments (see image below).
What is wrong? Could it be related to the fact we are using synchronous while the analytics script is set for async tracking?

For other events which are tracked asynchronously we do see related revenues.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely update to use Async code. What shopping cart are you using?

The event tracking code I use on a header search box is below. There are more parameters available I only have the first two set.

`onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site wide', 'Search']);"`